# UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidity false Transaction mined but execution failed

Tags: remix, uniswap

The two tokens have been approve to the router contract, but they always fail when the addLiquidity method is called. "false Transaction mined but execution failed" is displayed in remix.
Transaction hash：
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x918668d3b0218cf8861b48a5b763ad5ffdd1cb35b4629a0ce44886141a2bbe0d
[image]
[image]

Comment: After looking at the internal transaction it seems the contract breaks after at `IUniswapV2Pair(pair).initialize(token0, token1)` from [UniswapV2Factory.createPair](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xfba01b5b3f25f75a5a1f3967804867aabde065cd#code) and before `TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom` at [`UniswapV2Router02.addLiquidity`](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x3a9df1d9337c95c710fe4baf097b1db8299843d8#code). The only place that look suspiciuos is `pairFor` called from getReserves. It uses a hash that depends on the compiled contract.

Answer (score 0):

I met the exact same issue and spent 5 hours to finally found the root cause.

`addLiquidity` invokes `_addLiquidity` and then fails at:

```
(uint reserveA, uint reserveB) = UniswapV2Library.getReserves(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
```

Inside `getReserves` it calls `pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB)`.

The author didn't update the `init code hash` which is used to calculate the pair address, cauing `IUniswapV2Pair(pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB)).getReserves()` revert because the pair not found.

This often happens when you deploy your own Uniswap and forget to update INIT_CODE_HASH.

Comment: hi bai Bing, I think I am facing the same problem. Can you explain hoy can I update INIT_CODE_HASH?